# Groovy PromiseMap - Can I limit the asynchronous thread pool?

Tags: grails, asynchronous, groovy, promise

I am making a (quick and dirty) Batching API that allows the UI to send a selection of REST API calls and get results for all of them at once.

I am using PromiseMap to make some asynchronous REST calls to the relevant services, which get collected afterward.

There could be a large number of threads that need to run, and I would like to throttle the number of threads that run at the same time, similar to Executor's thread pool.

Is this possible without physically separating the threads into multiple PromiseMaps and chaining them? I haven't found anything online describing limiting the thread pool.

```
//get requested calls
JSONArray callsToMake=request.JSON as JSONArray 

//registers calls in promise map
def promiseMap = new PromiseMap()
//Can I limit this Map as a thread pool to, say, run 10 at a time until finished

data.each {
def tempVar=it
promiseMap[tempVar.id]={makeCall(tempVar.method, "${basePath}${tempVar.to}" as String, tempVar.body)}
}

def result=promiseMap.get()
def resultList=parseResults(result)
response.status=HttpStatusCodes.ACCEPTED
render resultList as JSON
```

I'm hoping there's a fairly straight-forward setting that I may be ignorant of.

Thank you.

Comment: protip, you don't need threads for making multiple async calls, just not blocking will do

Comment: Benjamin, the intention *is* to block the return of this call until all those async calls have finished and collecting their results and sending them back at once. Blocking is intentional, the threading is specifically to allow that blocking and collect the responses - if there is another way to make a bunch of async and then block until all come back I am open to whatever suggestion you might provide. My question regards how to then throttle so that 1000 calls don't burst the servers at once. What would you propose to accomplish these goals?

Comment: I have no idea :D To be fair, in Scala (setting the `ExecutionContext`) , JavaScript (`{concurrency: 8}`) or C# (`.WithDegreeOfParallelism(8)`) I'd know the answer. You can of course implement this yourself.

Comment: Of course, and I know how to do it using other approaches that aren't as ideal. Promises are Groovy's multithreading, so I am hoping there is a way already built in to throttle down the threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Async implementation in Grails is GPars. To configure the number of threads you need to use a GParsPool. See:

http://gpars.org/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html#dataParallelism_parallelCollections_GParsPool

Example:

```
withPool(10) {...}
```

Comment: Hi Graeme. Ok, so GPars would be better to use then Promises from the sounds of it. I thought Promises were the default in the newer versions though since they're in the grails.async package? Regardless, I'll have to read your link a little better, but it sounds like what we'd want. Can GPars block the controller from returning until all threads have completed?

Comment: I will be unable to try this today, but the documentation looks like what I need, so I'm going to give you credit, Graeme. Thank you!

Comment: Is using GPars still the recommended way to achieve a pool of reusable threads in grails-async 3 (4?) or is there some built in mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

withPool doesn't seem to be working. Just incase if anyone is looking to limit threads here is what i did. We can create a custom Group with custom ThreadPool and specify the number of the Threads.

```
def customGroup = new DefaultPGroup(new DefaultPool(true, 5))
try {
  Dataflow.usingGroup(customGroup, {
    def promises = new PromiseList()
    (1..100).each { number ->
      promises << {
        log.info "Performing Task ${number}"
        Thread.sleep(200)
        number++
      }
    }
    def result = promises.get()
  })
}
finally {
  customGroup.shutdown()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
runtime 'org.grails:grails-async-gpars'
```

at build.gradle
And

```
GParsExecutorsPool.withPool(10){service ->
    Shop.list().each{shop ->
        Item.list().each{item ->
            service.submit({createOrder(shop, item)} as Runnable)
        }
    }
}
```

in your Service for example